# SOQL performance of joins

Tags: soql, performance, outer-join

Considering the following scenario:

Objects: `Child__c`, `Parent1__c`, `Parent2__c`

Relationships:

- Child__c - Parent1__c (Lookup)
- Child__c - Parent2__c (Master-detail)

I want to query for Parent1 and Parent2 (Many Parent2 will be related to Parent1) and I want to keep the relationship between them (introduced through Child__c).
Child__c is just a junction object in this case.

I have 2 options:

Pseudo SOQL:

`Select Child__c.Parent1__r, Child__c.Parent2__r from Child__c`

or

```
Select Id, Name, ..., (Select Parent2__r.Id, Parent2__r.Name FROM Child__r) FROM Parent1__c
```

Because the relationship is not that simple, SOQL number 2 fits my purpose better.

However, I'm concerned of the performance of the nested SELECT statement.

So my main question is, are these cases optimized?
This would be a regular JOIN in any SQL language.

Would I suffer any perofmance degradation in this case?

Any reason to prefer option 1 over option 2 or vice versa?

Comment: With Option 1, you are going to have to use an apex loop to reconstruct the relationships, but option 2 has already grouped them by Parent1. Option 2 might be a little less efficient in SOQL, but the savings in logic to process them is also a factor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see some incredible depth on query cost in [Developing Selective Force.com Queries through the Query Resource Feedback Parameter Beta](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Developing_Selective_Force.com_Queries_through_the_Query_Resource_Feedback_Parameter_Pilot). Long story short, only your query filters (the `WHERE` clause) affect its cost. What style of [outer join](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/A_Deeper_look_at_SOQL_and_Relationship_Queries_on_Force.com) you use should have no impact. Note, however, that there is a maximum number of records you can retrieve with a Left Outer Join.

Comment: What kind of limit does the LEFT OUTER JOIN impose?
I don't see anything special on the total amount of records returned mentioned here:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_query_limits.htm

Comment: You start to get some errors or data loss over a certain threshold. I think it's a thousand children to a single parent, but I can't remember exactly and it's hard to search from my phone.

Comment: @elian see for example http://opfocus.com/aggregate-query-has-too-many-rows-for-direct-assignment-use-for-loop/

Comment: I tried using the Query Plan option on the developer console with the following results:
Nested SELECTs
Leading Operation Type: TableScan
Cost: 1.3
Notes: Not considering filter for optimization because unindexed. Table: Task__c Fields: ["IsDeleted"]

Adding a WHERE clause lowered the cost to 0???

No nested SELECTs:

Leading Operation Type: TableScan
Cost: 3.6
Notes: Not considering filter for optimization because unindexed. Table: Task__c Fields: ["IsDeleted"]

Answer (score 0):

You can use child-to-parent query as child object having multiple parent objects.

```
SELECT Id, Parent1__r.Id, Parent2__r.Id FROM Child__c
```

You can add fields you needed. But keep in mind

> Keep the number of fields to be searched or queried to a minimum.
>   Using a large number of fields leads to a large number of
>   permutations, which can be difficult to tune.

Have a look at more on [relationship queries limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_query_limits.htm).

Comment: I know, I can, this is example_1 from my post, but it's a bit more inconvenient to use it in this case. That's why I'm asking if there are performance implications of using the nested SELECT.